# vsftpd log file location?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Can someone tell me where is located the log file for vsftpd? I'm trying to learn how to install and configure a ftp server and I can't seem to find the log file. Can anybody tell me how to configure the service to make a log file or where is located?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The log file for Ubuntu by default is `/var/log/vsftpd.log`.  The setting is in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

The default could be modified by specifying a different pathname (`/etc/vsftp.conf` entry):

```
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.                     
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

Comment: If you'd like to view a live, realtime log of all events happening on the FTP server, do `tail -f vsftpd.log`. Tail is a program that displays the 'tail' of a file, `-f` tells it to follow any data appended to the file, in this case, any new log entries in the ftp log `vsftpd.log`.

Answer (score 7):

The logging of vsftpd is a bit more complex than other responses show. There are three logging mechanism, here is an example config of `/etc/vsftpd.conf` where I have added some comments for self-explanation:

```
# Below verbose log is for transfer/upload, formatted for common tools stats.
# Use command: tail -f /var/log/xferlog
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES

# Below verbose log is for FTP commands and responses.
# By default, logs were written to syslog instead of file.
# Use command: tail -f /var/log/vsftpd.log
# Use command: logread -f
log_ftp_protocol=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
syslog_enable=NO

# Allow log 1 and 2 to be written simultaneously.
dual_log_enable=YES
```

Once modified at your discretion, you must do a: `service vsftpd restart`

Due to the amount of logging generated, you might want to disable it as soon as you are finished debugging. More specifically, reverting to `syslog_enable=YES` will move back to logging into [RAM ringbuffer in OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/log.essentials) and avoid wear out flash.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens that the log is not filling any data, because the file doesn't exist. 
Create a log file:

```
touch /var/log/vsftpd.log
```

Then

```
service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: The touch /var/log/vsftpd.log shouldn't be necessary.  If it is needed, it should be a sign that there is a problem with the vsftpd installation or configuration.  The log file should automatically be created if it doesn't exist.  I tested it to make sure this would indeed be the case, by renaming the /var/log/vsftpd.log.  It was automatically recreated to log the vsftpd activity.  The recreating is the same thing that happens when the log file is rotated... moved to /var/log/vsftpd.log.1.